# How to return to setup for a new mac?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, login, setup

I was setting up my new Mac, I got to a step where there was this error

```
 unable to load identity provider: the identity provider is unable to be contacted. Check network settings or contact technical support
```

So I connected a docker stations with ethernet connected to it and restarted the computer.
This is were the wonk came into play: when the mac started up again it didnt show the setup step but instead it showed a login screen with a blank user and password.

I haven't set a user or password yet, i didn't get to that step???

how do i return the setup so i can create an account and use my mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I got help from the apple tech boys/girls.

1. shutdown your computer (press and hold power button till computer
   goes black)
2. power up your computer and immediately press and hold the keys `command`+`R`
3. a spinning world will show up if not connected to internet, connect to a network
4. then Macos utilities will pop up, on the MacOS Utilities screen, you will want to click Utilities > Terminal from the menubar at the top
5. type this command into the terminal `rm "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/var/db/.AppleSetupDone"` and press `return` to execute the command
6. now restart your computer and you will be back to the setup for your mac
7. follow the setup and create your computer account so this doesnt happen again